# Adding views lazily in UIScrollView slowing down App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, performance, uiscrollview, lazy-loading

> I am trying to implement a view with a mainScrollView. Inside that mainScrollView I have 10 UIView, each one is having subScrollView.Now, I want to add many (around 150 to 200) views(imageview,label,textview,uiview,webview,etc) inside each subScrollView.

something like this:

[Timeline ww2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XF7aVY2F5qc%22timeline%20ww2%22)  and
[History of Jazz](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKphAh701Js%22History%20of%20Jazz%22)

I have tried following:
**Method 1:**

> Lazy loading for each subScrollView to add views.

code for this:

```
-(void)loadInnerScrollViewLazily:(int)tag pageNo:(int)pageNo{

/// this array will contain all the views for subScrollView

NSMutableArray *array=[NSMutableArray array];
array=[self.tlScrollContentArray objectAtIndex:tag];  

if (pageNo < 0)
    return;
if (pageNo >= [array count])
    return;

UIView *controller = [array objectAtIndex:pageNo];
CGRect frame = [[array objectAtIndex:0] frame];
frame.origin.x = 350;
frame.origin.y = 0;
controller.frame = frame;

for (UIView* view in [mainScrollView subviews]) {
    for (UIScrollView* scroll in [view subviews]) {
        if ([scroll isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
              if (scroll.tag == tag+11) {

                [scroll addSubview:controller];   /// adds view in particular subScrollView

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

> This method is called in scrollViewDidScroll method, which checks perticular scrollView and removes view which is out of screen and then it will add views depending upon the condition.

This code is slowing down app as scrolling rate increases.

**Method 2:**

With the reference of [this](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/user-interface/creating-circular-and-infinite-uiscrollviews.html%22click%20here%22) tutorial:

> Add three UIView(each with subScrollView) in to mainScrollView. Updating content of subScrollView depending upon the condition.

But this solution is also slowing down my app as it is updating subScrollView every time it appears.

Is there any library or code available to manage this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think your code has many, many errors, and you would need to post your complete source to be helped. It's unclear if you are ever removing images from your scrollview. If not, that is your problem.

Look at Apple's sample PhotoScroller code: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html

This dequeues and manages the ImageViews on the scrollview... I implemented something similar based on this.